# Formal definition of an observer?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

What is the formal definition of an [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_%28special_relativity%29) in special relativity? I have seen a few:

1. The actual coordinate system.
2. The collection of synchronised clocks that cover the coordinate system.
3. A well reasoned person in the system.

But what is the actual definition? and can you give your source, thanks

Comment: You say you've seen a few formal definitions. What do you mean by "actual definition", then? Seems like there are several.

Comment: The question is philosophical, but I would define an observer as the coordinate system and collection of clocks. There shouldn't necessarily be a person in the system but some measuring device like a camera. The person can obtain all results later in his lab. This definition is based on Einstein's first manuscript on SR.

Comment: This is a great question even if the wording is awkward.  I'll try to find the time to compose an appropriate answer.

Comment: Thank God this question is about relativity and not quantum mechanics!

Comment: I thought it was God that quantum mechanics was all about.

Answer (score 13):

An observer is a timelike worldline with 4-velocity $u^{\mu}$ and an orthonormal basis $e_{\hat{\alpha}}$ with $e_{\hat{0}} = u$ such that $e_{\hat{\alpha}}$ is transported along the worldline under some transport law e.g. Lie transport, Fermi transport, or parallel transport. Physically the Lorentz frame represents a local set of three orthogonal meter sticks or gyroscopes and an ideal clock.

An observer can use $e_{\hat{\alpha}}$ to define a comoving local coordinate system (e.g. a Fermi-normal coordinate system) with clocks that are e.g. Einstein synchronized but the coordinate system isn't necessary to define the observer.

C.f. chapter 6 of MTW, section 13.6 of MTW, section 2.1 of Sachs and Wu "General Relativity for Mathematicians", and most importantly chapter 3 of Eric Gourgoulhon "Special Relativity in General Frames".

Comment: FenderLesPaul: "_An observer is a timelike worldline with 4-velocity $u^{\mu}$ and an orthonormal basis [...] C.f. chapter 6 of MTW, section 13.6 of MTW_" -- Comparing with MTW sec. 13.6 ("The proper reference frame of an accelerated observer") and chap. 6, especially sec. 6.4 ("The tetrad carried by a uniformly accelerated observer") it seems that your answer is dealing with "What's an orthonormal tetrad?", or "What's a proper reference frame of an accelerated observer?", instead of the OP question itself.

Comment: FenderLesPaul: "_Physically the Lorentz frame represents a local set of three orthogonal meter sticks or [...]_" -- That's apparently represented by **at least four distinct**, non-intersecting, time-like worldlines (i.e. one for each distinct physical "end" of such a stick); not just one.

Comment: @user12262, An observer is an orthonormal tetrad of the above kind, there is no distinction between them. In GR you can everywhere replace the notion of an observer with that of a local Lorentz frame and the calculations would go through the exact same. An observer is just a means of making local measurements in space-time using a set of rods, gyroscopes, and a clock. The gyroscopes are oriented according to a desired transport law as mentioned earlier, for example Fermi-transport if one wants inertial-guidance gyroscopes.

Comment: @user12262, the tetrad lives in the tangent space at any given event on the observer worldline so to lowest non-vanishing order the extent of the rods or meter sticks is negligible.

Comment: FenderLesPaul: "_An observer is an orthonormal tetrad of the above kind, there is no distinction between them._" -- MTW certainly draw a distinction: writing (e.g. in the title of §6.4) of "a tetrad **carried by** an observer", instead of "a tetrad **being (the same as)** an observer". "_[...] replace the notion of an observer with that of a local Lorentz frame_" -- Does this suggested replacement apply in [Einstein's prescription: "If the observer perceives the two flashes of lightning at the same time, then ..."](https://archive.org/stream/EinsteinRelativity/Einstein_Relativity_djvu.txt) ??

Comment: FenderLesPaul: "_[...] to lowest non-vanishing order the extent of the rods or meter sticks is negligible_" -- To lowest non-vanishing order ... of what ?? There is a principal distinction of whether two distinguishable participants (a.k.a. "material points", "principal identifiable points" (MTW, Box 13.1), "observers" ...) were coincident, or not. A "_rod_" ("_stick_") means a pair of distinguishable "ends" which were **not** coincident; and the distinction to having been coincident is not negligible as a matter of principle.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the formal definition of an
>   [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_%28special_relativity%29)
>   in special relativity? I have seen a few:
>
> 1. The actual coordinate system.
> 2. The collection of synchronised clocks that cover the coordinate system.
> 3. A well reasoned person in the system.
>
> But what is the actual definition?

In #3, what is missing is that the observer's state of motion, i.e., normalized velocity four-vector, needs to be defined, and what shouldn't be included is the stuff about it being an actual person. An "observer" in the SR sense can be a totally impersonal mathematical description, not even necessarily a physical object.

If the observer is *inertial*, then there is a one-to-one correspondence between normalized velocity vectors and Minkowski coordinate systems. Therefore it doesn't matter in this case whether you do a definition in the style of 1 or 3. However, SR is compatible with an arbitrary coordinate system, which can be defined by any change of coordinates that is well behaved (a diffeomorphism). (GR isn't required for this.) For a generic choice of coordinates, there is no way to define a corresponding observer. Therefore if you're allowing non-inertial observers, approach #3 is the only one that works. In that situation, the observer could be both rotating and accelerating, so you end up with the definition given in FenderLesPaul's answer.

Number 2 doesn't work, because it doesn't define anything about the observer's spatial coordinate system, e.g., it doesn't tell us how the observer is oriented.

Comment: Ben Crowell: "_[...] there is a one-to-one correspondence between normalized velocity vectors and Minkowski coordinate systems_" -- Rather, there is a one-to-one correspondence between "_normalized velocity vectors_" (i.e. with respect to one particular choice of inertial system as reference) and certain **equivalence classes** of "_Minkowski coordinate systems_"; where each equivalence class contains all "_Minkowski coordinate systems_" which are equivalent "modulo" translations, rotations, and being either "spherical", or "Cartesian", or any other "spatial" coordinate assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no single definition, since it varies according to author. Personally, I think the term should just be abandoned. It's too ambiguous. It mixes up two ideas that need to be cleanly separated, but often aren't: the frame of reference as a grid of sensors, and a single sensor that receives incoming information, like a camera.

Mixing up these two ideas is a recipe for misunderstanding.

Comment: John O: "_two ideas that need to be cleanly separated [...] a grid of sensors, and a single sensor_" -- Correct: these are two separate notions. Now, in order to separate them cleanly suitable distinct verbiage (terminology) must be available and used consistently. The key phrase here is **"grid of"** (or "system") which implies and refers to several distinct elements, possibly in some particular relation(s) between each other. Consequently there must be verbiage/terminology to denote such elements, namely as "sensors", or "material points", or: "observers".

Answer (score -1):

An "observer" in the theory of relativity means any individual who is capable, or, in the context of thought experiments, any material point or principal identifiable point to which the capability is attributed,

- to collect perceptions,
- to distinguish the perceptions collected, and
- to judge the coincidence (or otherwise: the sequence) of distinct collected perceptions.

Reference:
A. Einstein, "Relativity. The Special and General Theory", chap. 8:

> [*If the observer perceives the two flashes of lightning at the same time, then [...]*](https://archive.org/stream/EinsteinRelativity/Einstein_Relativity_djvu.txt)

Like all of Physics and Geometry, the "observer" notion of RT as well as the derivation of geometric relations between observers (to characterize sets of distinct observers as a "*system*" or "*reference frame*") stand of course without any assignment or even particular choice of coordinates.